# Inverse matrix of an $n$x$n$ matrix, which is given below.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Now, I'm stuck on how to get the inverse of this matrix. I tried $3$x$3$ version on this matrix but I still have difficulty on finding a pattern on getting the inverse matrix.
$$V= \displaystyle{\begin{bmatrix} 
\sum_{1 \neq k} m_{1k} +(\gamma_1+\rho_1\tau_1) & -m_{21}  & \cdots & -m_{n1}\\
-m_{12}& \sum_{2 \neq k} m_{2k} +(\gamma_2+\rho_2\tau_2) & \cdots & -m_{n2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-m_{1n}&-m_{2n}& \cdots & \sum_{n \neq k} m_{nk} +(\gamma_n+\rho_n\tau_n)
\end{bmatrix}},$$
where $k=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Why do you think there is some closed form?

Comment: _Any_ square matrix has that form for appropriate values of the parameters. So "finding" the inverse of this matrix is the same as finding the inverse of _every_ matrix...

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_{ij}$ be an entry to matrix $V$, and $\tilde{a_{ij}}$ be an entry to the inverse matrix ($V^{-1}$) of $V$. Then $V^{-1}$ defined by, for $i,j=1,\ldots,n$,

i. $\displaystyle{\tilde{a_{ii}} = \frac{det(A-i^{th}(\textrm{row and column}))}{det(A)}},$

ii.$\displaystyle{\tilde{a_{ij}} = \frac{\sum_{1 \neq k} a_{ik} det(A-i^{th}(\textrm{row and column})-j^{th}\textrm{row} - k^{th} \textrm{column})}{det(A)}}$, where $k=1,\ldots,n$.